# Store boolean variable in url dispatching

Tags: python, regex, django, url

The following url definition should pass whether `results/` is present in the url:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<results>(results/)?)shorten/$', views.shorten, name='shorten')
```

Currently it passes `results/` or `None` which is sufficient for a simple:

```
if results:
    pass
```

But it would be more elegant to have `True` and `False`. How could this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could have two URL patterns and pass `results` in the kwargs:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/shorten/$', views.shorten, {'results': True}, name='shorten'),
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/shorten/$', views.shorten, {'results': False}, name='shorten'),
```

If you don't want to do this, then there isn't currently a simple way to cast the `results` string to a boolean value. You could write a middleware or decorator, but that would be overkill.

Comment: You can actually reverse both patterns with the same name if you pass in the `results` parameter with a `True` or `False` value. It [compares additional arguments to the defaults](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1ebd295082bb0e6b230cf3bc39fd04bee71c2bd7/django/urls/resolvers.py#L443) and only matches the pattern if the values match.

Comment: @knbk thanks for the explanation and link to the code. I've changed the answer to use the same name for both patterns.

Comment: @knbk Could you please give an example of how to reverse the patterns?

Comment: @R3turnz You just pass in the `results` kwarg with the appropriate value: `reverse('shorten', kwargs={'question_id': 1, 'results': True})` or `{% url 'shorten' question_id=1 results=True %}`.